# Blazor server, call api controller delete/{filename} to delete file. 404 response

Tags: api, blazor, http-delete

I have an api that works in most functions, but not on my HttpDelete where I got 404 response.

```
    [Route("/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UploadController : ControllerBase
    
..

    [HttpDelete("delete/{filename}")]
    public IActionResult Delete(string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            var filePath = Path.Combine(grundPath, ulPath, filename);
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
                return StatusCode(200);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, ex.Message);
        }
        return StatusCode(500);
    }
```

My Blazor component :

```
..
@inject HttpClient Http
..
string url = $"delete/{filename}"
HttpResponseMessage response = await Http.DeleteAsync(url);
..
```

I have tried to set url = $"https://localhost:XXXX/delete..... but same result.
Filename are in form "picture.png"

> StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content:
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponse Content, Headers: { Set-Cookie:
> x-ms-gateway-slice=estsfd; path=/; secure; httponly DATE...

I'm a newbie on api controller so I have no clue what I missed. Don't even know where to start google...

[EDIT : Added Swagger to project]

After analysed with Swagger, I got this in swagger :

> [DELETE] /delete/{filename}

Added a filename and execute, got this requested url :

> https://localhost:7285/delete/_eskilssk%C3%A4rmklipp.PNG

And the file are deleted.  So far so good.

Change / added code to this :

```
string filename = WebUtility.UrlEncode(fil.Namn);
string baseUrl = $"https://localhost:7285/delete/{filename}";
await JsRuntime.ToastrSuccess("Info : " + baseUrl);
HttpResponseMessage response = await Http.DeleteAsync(baseUrl);
```

My Toastr gives me :

> https://localhost:7285/delete/_eskilssk%C3%A4rmklipp.PNG
> same as swagger...

But this in my output i Visual studio :

> System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.LogicalHandler: Information: Start
> processing HTTP request DELETE
> https://localhost:7285/delete/_eskilsskärmklipp.PNG
> System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler: Information: Sending
> HTTP request DELETE
> https://localhost:7285/delete/_eskilsskärmklipp.PNG

Could it be my encoding that's wrong?

My Program.cs, maybe wrong order?

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
    options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireClaim("role", "Admin"));
});

builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
}, ServiceLifetime.Transient);


builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();

builder.Services.AddScoped<>(); // Some repositories
..

builder.Services.AddScoped<DialogService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<NotificationService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<TooltipService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ContextMenuService>();

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();  // Remove when publish!!!

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
app.MapBlazorHub();

app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Blazor API V1");
});

app.Run();
```

2022-11-10
Problem found, when I comment out // app.UseAuthentication and app.UseAuthorization I could reach the API from my component. It's a security problem and doesn't have anything to do with this original question.
Start a new question with more correct information.

[Blazor server and API in same project, 404 not found when app.UserAuth is activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74386942/blazor-server-and-api-in-same-project-404-not-found-when-app-userauth-is-activa)

Comment: The action don't return 404, but the client get 404. ASP.NET Core return 404 when the url  match none route . I suppose that the route segment is defined in the controller.

Comment: @vernou This : [Route("/[controller]"] on top of my controller file? (add some text above)

Comment: try inverting [ApiController]  [Route("[controller]")]

Comment: Install swagger in my application now and it works when I use swagger so the error must be in my blazor component, how I call my Deletecontroller.

Comment: What is the name of the controller class? `FilesController`?

Comment: @vernou : you mean this?   public class UploadController : ControllerBase    I use this to upload files to a secure folder. If something goes wrong when user add data to my database, I will call this Delete function to remove the uploaded file from folder again so I'm not having unlinked files.

Comment: Try without special char in file's name. It will indicate if it is an encoding issue.

Comment: Add some more information, I copy my API to a new project and run that and point my baseURL to that page (runs on another port) and then it works. So maybe I missed something in my startupfiles that are needed when component and api are in same project?

Comment: No, there is no such page.  I will try to create a clean blazor server project and put my api-controller there and see if it works.

Comment: Same code works in a fresh project so there must be something wrong in my settings / program.cs somewhere.

Comment: @Henk Holterman, I think I have found the problems. My app need authentication and ofcause the API too, so I need to solve how I could give my blazor component access to my controller.

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET Core, the action's route is : `[controller]/[action]`. In your case :

```http
/upload/delete/{filename}
```

The client need to call this url like :

```cs
..
@inject HttpClient Http
..
string url = $"upload/delete/{filename}"
HttpResponseMessage response = await Http.DeleteAsync(url);
..
```

If you want the action's url is `delete/{filename}`, then you can start the action route segment by `/`. ASP.NET Core MVC will ignore the controller route segment when the action route segment start by `/` like :

```cs
[HttpDelete("/delete/{filename}")]
public IActionResult Delete(string filename)
```

Comment: I tried your tip, can't get it to work. Have added one uriencoder so my filstring are uri encoded so the string are the same as the one swagger use but doesn't help.  Have update my question above with new information.